# Trigger onChange event manually

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to call my onChange manually.

Here's my select with onChange (I pass onChangeSelect as a prop from parent component)

```
return(
   <Form Control disabled={disabled}
      <NativeSelect ref={ref} onChange={onChangeSelect}>
       ...
```

And I'd like to call that onChange every time my variable changes and is empty

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (requiredSelect[0].length > 0 || id === "root1") { setDisabled(false) }
    else { ref.current.value = ([[], []]); ref.current.onChange ; setDisabled(true); }
}, [requiredSelect])
```

And here's onChangeSelect in parent component

```
<Child onChangeSelect={(e) => rootChange(e)}>
```

and what it does

```
const rootChange = e => { setRootSelect(e.target.value.split(',')); }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution here would be to change the definition of your `rootChange` function to accept the `value` instead of the `event` itself.

```
const rootChange = value => { setRootSelect(value.split(',')); }

// In parent:
<Child onChangeSelect={rootChange}>

// Select
<NativeSelect ref={ref} onChange={(e) => onChangeSelect(e.target.value)}>
```

You can trigger the function manually with:

```
onChangeSelect(whateverValueYouWant); // notice that you need the brackets when calling the function.
```

Answer in Typescript

```
//Child Component
type PropsType = {
  onChange: (value: string) => void;
  value: string;
};
const CustomInput: FC<PropsType> = (props: PropsType) => {
 const onChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    props.onChange(event.target.value);
  };
  return (<input
          onChange={onChange}
          type="text"
          value={props.value}></input>);
};

//Parent Component
const [input, setInput] = React.useState('');

<CustomInput
            onChange={(value: string) => {
              setInput(value);
            }}
            value={input}></CustomInput>
```

Comment: Do I use ref to trigger this onChange? Otherwise I just get: 'onChange' is not defined

Comment: you are passing `onChange` as a prop, right? just call that function directly.

Comment: Im not passing it as a prop, Im passing onChangeSelect as a prop. 
Sorry if I misunderstood.

Comment: you can call `onChangeSelect` then, made the change in answer